# error (400) when putting whitenoise in django cpanel whit debug in false

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, static, cpanel, whitenoise

I get a 400 error on the entire page when I put this in the settings.py: STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
If I have the debug set to true nothing happens and everything is fine, but if I change it to false it gives me the error

On the only page that this does not happen is on one that I do not have a static load, which only has files that I send from the admin